# Rails 3 - custom validation to check date type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

I want to validate my date (which actually have DATE type) in model. So, i try to write for that simle method and run it via validation.

```
Teacher

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :teacher_birthday # DATE type!

  belongs_to :user

  validates :teacher_birthday, :presence => true,
                               :unless   => :date_is_correct?

  ########

  def date_is_correct?    
     parsed_data = Date._parse(:teacher_birthday)
     input_day   = parsed_data[:mday]
     input_month = parsed_data[:mon]
     input_year  = parsed_data[:year]

     correct_days   = 1..31
     correct_months = 1..12
     correct_year   = 1900..2000

     if ( correct_days.member? input_day ) and ( correct_months.member? input_month) and
        ( correct_year.member? input_year)
        true
     else
        errors.add(:teacher_birthday, 'date is invalid')
        false     
     end      
  end
```

When i run rspec a lot of tests fail.

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into String
# ./app/models/teacher.rb:56:in `_parse'
# ./app/models/teacher.rb:56:in `date_is_correct?'
```

I suppose i do something wrong. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect `Date._parse(:teacher_birthday)` to work?

Comment: Why not? Recommend me better way then, please!

Comment: Maybe `Date._parse(teacher_birthday)` ???

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessary at all. If Date.parse(:teacher_birthday) returns a date and doesn't raise an exception, you have a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

`Date._parse` expects a string-value containing a date and will in your code always try to parse 'teacher_birthday'. You need to get the value of the field first and pass the value to `Date._parse`. ActiveRecord creates methods with the same name as the field to get the value.
Any of the following will work:

Short way

```
parsed_data = Date._parse(teacher_birthday)
```

Identically to the first (the `self.` is added for you during parsing)

```
parsed_data = Date._parse(self.teacher_birthday)
```

Explicit way

```
parsed_data = Date._parse(self[:teacher_birthday])
```

Answer (score 0):

A new gem has been created to help [validate types in rails](https://github.com/yez/validates_type) and an [explanatory blog post](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/05/10/validates-type/) exists to answer more of the "why" it was created in the first place.

With this library your code would simple be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_type :teacher_birthday, :date
end
```

This will throw an exception when anything except a a `Date` is assigned to `:teacher_birthday`.